# how to get the actual constructor of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

is there a way to get the actual called function used to instance the object?

```
function A(){}
A.prototype.test = function(){};

function B(){}
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

B.prototype.test = function(){};

var x = new B();
alert(x.constructor);   // alerts "A"
```

i'm also interested in cross browser support

thanks

Comment: Actually, `console.log(x.constructor)` returns `function A(){}`. "Never" use `alert` to debug, it converts it's parameters `toString()`

Comment: alert(x.constructor === B); alerts FALSE

Comment: You want to call to the constructor through the instance x?

Comment: I Mean: x.constructor run A function?

Comment: Or you want to get the function B?

Comment: I want to get the function B, the one that i used to instance the object

Comment: After `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);`, try `B.prototype.constructor = B;`.

Comment: @Rikonator there isn't a way to do this automatically?

Comment: ok I get it. @Rikonator if you answer I will accept your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After this sort of inheritance, you need to explicitly set the constructor of the 'subclass'.

```
...
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
...
```

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to do this automatically. Even Google's Closure library has something like this;

```
var inherit = function(subClass, superClass) {
    var temp = function() {};
    temp.prototype = superClass.prototype;
    subClass._super = superClass.prototype;
    subClass.prototype = new temp();

    subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
};
```

So, if you have a constructor with arguments, you can simply do something like

```
var ParentClass = function(arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
};

ParentClass.prototype.show = function() {
    console.log('Parent!');
    console.log('arg1: ' + this.arg1);
    console.log('arg2: ' + this.arg2);
};

var ChildClass = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    ParentClass.call(this, arg1, arg2);
    this.arg3 = arg3;
};

inherit(ChildClass, ParentClass);

ChildClass.prototype.show = function() {
    console.log('Child!');
    console.log('arg1: ' + this.arg1);
    console.log('arg2: ' + this.arg2);
    console.log('arg3: ' + this.arg3);
};
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nK28J/)**.